# How to write (String): Int function?

Tags: scala

I'd like to convert an `Array[String]` to an `Array[Int]`, using map method. What is the shortest way to get a function of type `(String) => Int` to pass as map argument?

I'd prefer convert existing builtin ones like `Integer.valueOf` in some way.
A method of argument binding to shorten the construction like `def parseInt(s:String) = Integer.parseInt(s, 10)` would also be great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
scala> Array("1", "2", "3") map(_.toInt)
res4: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
scala> def parseInt(s:String) = Integer.parseInt(s, 10)
parseInt: (s: String)Int

scala> Array("1", "2", "3") map parseInt
res7: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What does "_" from "_.toInt" mean?

Comment: It is a placeholder, equivalent to Array("1", "2", "3") map (x => x.toInt), which means "for each element in array, apply .toInt method on it, and construct a new array", which will result in Array("1".toInt, "2".toInt, "3".toInt)

Comment: This is a good resource on Scala's "Placeholder Syntax": http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=scala+placeholder+syntax&source=bl&ots=FKtlWGELnw&sig=d_XC9xbr3-4Q8968ZRmzEYamsYY&hl=en&ei=I328TJyaA47KjAf24KnRDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=scala%20placeholder%20syntax&f=false

Answer (score 3):

First, let's define an array of strings:

```
scala> val foo = Array("1", "2", "3")
foo: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

The most obvious way would be to use Scala's `toInt()`, available on strings:

Definition:

```
// StringLike.scala
def toInt: Int         = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(toString)
```

(Note: `toString`, defined elsewhere, simply converts the `StringLike` object to a Java string)

Your code:

```
scala> foo.map(_.toInt)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

`Integer.valueOf()` also works, but notice you will get `Array[Integer]` instead of `Array[Int]`:

```
scala> foo.map(Integer.valueOf)
res1: Array[java.lang.Integer] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

While we're at it, a for comprehension would work almost as well, except you'd be invoking `toInt` yourself, instead of passing it over to `map()`

```
scala> for (i<-foo) yield i.toInt
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
Array("1", "2", "3") map Integer.valueOf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val strs = Array("1", "2")
strs: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(1, 2)

scala> strs.map(_.toInt)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```